# Using max-width & width:100%, what's the correct way?

Tags: css

I'm using this CSS, it works in all browsers except chrome.

CSS:

```css
#header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="header">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the #header to extend as far as possible, but at a maximum of 1024px. On chrome it just extends 100%.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I see it fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/SrAwx/

Comment: works fine with chrome, firefox & safari latest version.

Comment: @Alvaro: Sorry, Im using with a table object. not a div: http://jsfiddle.net/SrAwx/1/

Comment: @Gerve can you please post your markup here (edit your question). Posting code only on external sources (jsfiddle, etc.) is less than ideal.

Comment: @KP. No problem. will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display: block` to the CSS.

```
#header {
    background:red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height:100px;
    display: block;
}​
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvkxR/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "smallest width", using the above I was able to get it to grow to the max-width reliably (i.e. by changing it to max-width 600px)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is set the `table` to `display: block`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SrAwx/2/